# SilverStripe crop image from upload on template

Tags: image, crop, silverstripe

I have uploaded a file through the silverstripe's CMS and need to display that image in the homepage cropped. I understand doing it while looping through many images, but if it is just one (and a specific one) how can i do that? can be done in the template directly? or something needs to be done in the controller first? (I'm very new to silverstripe so if it's obvious forgive my ignorance)

Comment: Without any additional structure, you will need to do both. The controller would be used to isolate which image you want to use (from your assets), and your template variables would be used to place and crop the image.

Comment: yeah, that's what i thought.... Thanks @jakxnz

Comment: Do you know where I can see examples of how to this? or some documentation that includes cases like this? thanks!

Comment: @jakxnz how is that you isolate the image in the controller? all the examples i find are to loop over lists...

Comment: I believe your question is too broad to answer. Can you please expand your question to include some extra detail, and some example code?

Comment: no prob @jakxnz! i finally did it, was enough to use `File::find('the_path_to_the_file_here');` and then send that to the template. Then in the template do `$ControllerName.CroppedImage(640, 360)` and all good :D

Answer (score 0):

Ale Van Houtte, if you have a page that has_one image, then in the template you would do something like `$YourImageRelationName.Fill(100, 100)`, or if you wanted to manage the tag  itself it would be `<img src="$YourImageRelationName.Fill(100, 100).URL" />` or something like that.

Comment: it doesn't :\ basically it's a space that it's to place some special event or something arbitrary, so the image will be arbitrary, the link, everything...